# Android TurnBasedMutliplayer No Callbacks

Tags: android, multiplayer

I have been following the guide here to add TurnBased Multiplayer to an android game. https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#before_you_begin. I have coded everything up and am able to have users login to google play services. Then using the BaseGameUtils I attempt to create a match using the following function below but I never receive a callback other than timeouts.

```
void CreateMatch(MatchConfig matchConfig) {
    int minAutoMatchPlayers = 2;
    int maxAutoMatchPlayers = 2;

    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = TurnBasedMatchConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);

    TurnBasedMatchConfig curMatch = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder()
            .setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria)
            .build();

    if (!googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Not connected to google api so unable to create a match");
        return;
    }

    // Attempt creating a match and set this as the callback
    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch(googleApiClient, curMatch).setResultCallback(this, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

I implemented the `ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult>` in the same class, but as mentioned never get any callbacks.

```
public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult initiateMatchResult) {
    Status status = initiateMatchResult.getStatus();
    Log.d(TAG, "Match creation status " + status);
```

Im not sure how to debug this further or why im not getting any callbacks. I have:

Setup my developer account and added/enable turnbased games. The App is in Alpha there.

Setup the OAuth key and AppId in the manifest.

Tested with signed APKs. Tested with two different google accounts on
   two different phones. 
Tried using `Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.loadMatchesByStatus(googleApiClient,
   TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_ALL).setResultCallback(this);` but
   it always returns 0 matches.

Any information on how to debug this
   further would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding

Implement OnInvitationReceivedListener and OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener

to your activity?

Also
In onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(mGoogleApiClient, this) and Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.registerMatchUpdateListener(mGoogleApiClient, this)

Comment: After trying some of your suggestions I found that I have some issues with linking my app/client ID thank you! `04-25 20:27:20.826 11780-12038/? E/Volley: [6295] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/turnbasedmatches/create?language=en_US
04-25 20:27:20.889 11780-6958/? E/DataHolderOperation: There is no linked app associated with this client ID.`